# Chrome extension that enables chatting with users on same page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've seen Chrome extensions that claim to do such thing, but the chat page they provide are all separate page from the original web page, which is really inconvenient. Is there existing plugin that can do this? I may want to build one myself but I'm guessing there may be some permission issue, since that would be showing content from 3rd party.

Is it possible to insert content like a chat box into all different web pages using Chrome extension?

Comment: You should do some searching yourself and do some work before asking questions here. If you have already done those, you'd better provide some code samples or tell us your approach and where you got stuck; therefore we can suggest solutions if we can. Now, your question seems unrelevant to SO and smells like an advert to me

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes, there is.
This one does exactly what you want, works for HTTPS sites as well since the connection to server this extension use is under HTTPS. It inserts a chat box to the original page and you can change the size of the chatbox or minimize it.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chat-anywhere/bldcellajihanglphncgjmceklbibjkk

Comment: Is there better extension out there that satisfy PO's requirement? Someone downvoted this...

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but it could be that it was downvoted for not being a programming-related question/answer, since that is what SO is for.

Comment: @Arch1tect [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347809/off-topic-questions-asking-for-offsite-resources-and-links-posted-in-comments). This question should be closed, not answered, because it's off-topic and by answering such questions [You are contributing to the problem of bad posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347809/off-topic-questions-asking-for-offsite-resources-and-links-posted-in-comments#comment464982_347809)